# Value of variable referenced from another module does not change after it is changed in its own module

Tags: python

I started to write python programs for some time, but I am not so good at it, at present I meet a problem, it seems very strange, at least for me.

Assume we have two source files, called `A.py` and `B.py`, their contents are as below:

`A.py`

```
import B

__global__ = 'not set yet'

class Data:
    __var__ = 'not set yet'

def init():
    global __global__
    __global__ = 'value set for global'
    Data.__var__ = 'value set for class var'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()

    t = B.Test()
    t.display()

    print '============================'
    print 'global(in A):    ' + __global__
    print 'class var(in A): ' + Data.__var__
```

`B.py`

```
import A

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.glo = A.__global__
        self.var = A.Data.__var__

    def display(self):
        print 'global:          ' + self.glo
        print 'class var:       ' + self.var
        print '============================'
        print 'global(in B):    ' + A.__global__
        print 'class var(in B): ' + A.Data.__var__
```

then I ran `python A.py`, the output is as following:

```
global:          not set yet
class var:       not set yet
============================
global(in B):    not set yet
class var(in B): not set yet
============================
global(in A):    value set for global
class var(in A): value set for class var
```

In my opinion, the first 4 outputs should coincide with the last 2 outputs, but the fact is not, seems the value is set during class and method definition and cannot be changed. It is very different from many other languages, such as Java. So, could any one help explain this, or paste me some links to help understand it? And is there any workaround to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Kelvin

==============edit==============

Thanks @icktoofay, @hop and @RocketDonkey, after I tried the code below, I do find the root cause:

```
import sys
import A
import __main__

__global__ = 'not set yet'

class Data:
    __var__ = 'not set yet'

def init():
    global __global__
    __global__ = 'value set for global'
    Data.__var__ = 'value set for class var'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()

    for key in sys.modules.keys():
        if key in ['__main__', 'A']:
            print key + ' : ' + sys.modules[key].__file__
    print '===================='
    print 'A: ' + A.__global__
    print 'A: ' + A.Data.__var__
    print '===================='
    print __main__.__global__
    print __main__.Data.__var__
```

the output is:

```
__main__ : A.py
A : D:\test\python\A.py
====================
A: not set yet
A: not set yet
====================
value set for global
value set for class var
```

It is because file `A.py` was imported twice, one is named `__main__` and another is named `A`, the values were changed in module `__main__`, but for module `B`, the value is got from module `A`, so the value is not changed.

I do need to dive deeper for module importing of python. :-D

Comment: do not use circular imports

Comment: @hop yes, I do know this is not a good programming habit, but currently I just want to know the 'why', and I will modify my code and remove the circular import.

Comment: Your `str(sys.modules[key])` might be okay for debugging, but it's much better to instead just use `sys.modules[key].__file__`.

Comment: @icktoofay yeah, I used `str()` just for testing, I have updated the code as you advised, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circular imports (`A` imports `B`, `B` imports `A`) in combination with one of the modules being the main script is the problem.

### How Python imports modules

When you ask Python to import a module, it first looks through `sys.modules` to see if a module by that name is already there. If so, it just uses that module. If there is no module by that name, it makes a new module object, places it in `sys.modules`, and runs the appropriate Python code in that module.

### Main scripts

There's a popular idiom that's used in Python scripts: the ubiquitous

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

When Python wants to run the main script, it imports that module *with the name `__main__`*.

That's perfectly fine when your main script just does stuff with other modules, but when other modules want to do things to the main module again, you run into trouble: The script importing the main module again is probably importing it by a normal name (like in this case, `A`). Unfortunately, the already-loaded module is not named `A`; it's named `__main__`.

### Solutions

A very simple solution would simply be to remove the other modules' dependencies on the main module. Then you will not encounter this unintuitive behavior. One way you might do this is have the main script just be a stub that calls out to another module's `main` function or something.

A different solution would be to have the main script alter `sys.modules` manually to put itself under another name. This is a little hacky, but it works:

```
sys.modules['A'] = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Now you know.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks for your answer, just now I tested with some code, and did find the root cause, I will paste my code after my question.

Comment: @icktoofay: yes, we are talking about the same thing. that's why i didn't even wanted to bother beyond "don't do it!" i deleted my stuff to not add to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @icktoofay - I would put more stock in that answer than mine, so take this one with a grain of salt as it is my admittedly inexperienced understanding of the process:

As mentioned by others, your main issue is circular imports. Others will comment more intelligently, but the gist of what is happening is:

1. `import B` - this happens as soon as you run A.py`, so you then go to B.py and immediately come across   import A.
2. As `A` has a different name in the current namespace, it gets imported again (to verify this, add `print __name__` above `import B` in `A.py` - you'll see two different names appear).
3. When `A` gets imported into `B`, it brings the `__global__ = 'not seen yet'` declaration with it, so when you say `self.glo = A.__global__`, you are getting that variable (and not the modified one because that particular code doesn't get executed in *this* version of `A`).
4. Same with `A.Data.__var__` - you haven't run `init` in this module (because it isn't your 'main' `A`), so nothing has been modified yet.
5. Per the above, you can see why `A.__global__` and `A.Data.__var__` will also show 'not seen yet' - they haven't been modified and are the same as the variables above.
6. Your code in `A` in the `__main__` section executes as normal because it is operating on that version of the module, which does go through all of the initializations you specify.

Comment: yes, thanks for your answer, I did find the root cause just now. :-D